# Select rows with same id but only one row is needed

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the only row having a value of yes for a particular username

If both rows have yes for that particular username or both have no, then it should not appear in output.

Below is example sample and output. How it can be done using sql query?

```
+----------+-----+-------+
| username | id  | col2  |
+----------+-----+-------+
| a        | 1  | yes    |
| a        | 2  | yes    |
| b        | 3  | yes    |
| b        | 4  | no     |
| c        | 5  | no     |
| c        | 6  | no     |
+----------+----+--------+
```

output

```
+---------+---+------+
| username|id | col2 |
+---------+---+------+
| b       |3  | yes  |
+---------+---+------+
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this exercise you don't need joins or subqueries; all you need is GROUP BY and HAVING.

```
select username, 'yes' as col2
from   table_name
group by username
having min(col2) != max(col2)
```

**Edit** (to address the OP's restated question):

```
select username, min(id) keep (dense_rank last order by col2) as id, 'yes' as col2
from   table_name   [....   the rest as above]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  How would I incorporate a third field to display that would give a unique id number.  for example:

Comment: +----------+-------+
    | username | col2  |
    +----------+-------+
    | a        | yes   |
    | a        | yes   |
    | b        | yes   |
    | b        | no    |
    | c        | no    |
    | c        | no    |
    +----------+-------+

output
+----------+------+
| username | col2 |
+----------+------+
| b        | yes  |
+----------+------+

Comment: sorry, I will edit the original, I keep hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

If the row for each username are only  two

```
select t1.username , t1.col2
from mytable t1
inner mytable t2 on t1.username = t2.username 
            and t1.col2 = 'yes' and t2.col2 ='no'
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you could have more than two rows for each username, this will find usernames who only have a single yes.

```
SELECT username, MIN(id), col2
FROM YourTable
WHERE col2 = 'yes'
GROUP BY username, col2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```